# Doctrine | Between DateTime of a relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on a school project where we build a website for a cinema.
In the administration you can create movies and then you can create shows

I have 2 entities:

**Show**

```
$id
$name
$movie
...
$date (when the movie starts)
```

**Movie**

```
$id
$name
...
$shows
```

Now my problem is like on real cinema website I want that the schedule is from Thursday to Wednesday. But I dont get the Query right to return all movies within the date range:

**MovieRepository**

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('movie')
        ->innerJoin('movie.shows', 'shows')
        ->where('shows.date > :thursday')
        ->andWhere('shows.date < :wednesday')
        ->setParameters([
            'thursday' => $thursday,
            'wednesday' => $wednesday
        ]);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The Query just return the Movies (with all of their shows) where 1 or more shows are in the range.

See here (Thursday is 31.05. and Wednesday is 06.06):

if there is one show of this movie in the date range, all shows of this movie will be shown
[image]

---

**Solved it:**

I needed to make ->select() and choose booth tables.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('movie')
        ->innerJoin('movie.shows', 'shows');
        ->select('movie', 'shows')
        ->where('shows.date > :thursday')
        ->andWhere('shows.date < :wednesday')
        ->setParameters([
            'thursday' => $thursday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'wednesday' => $wednesday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ])
        ->orderBy('shows.date', 'ASC')
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to invert the query please like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('show')
        ->innerJoin('show.movie', 'movie')
        ->where('show.date > :thursday')
        ->andWhere('show.date < :wednesday')
        ->setParameters([
            'thursday' => $thursday,
            'wednesday' => $wednesday
        ]);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```